# How to use built-in default HDRi's in renders?

Tags: hdri

Blender 2.8 and newer contains a number of HDRi's in it by default for *LookDev*. I'd like to know how to use them in final renders (EEVEE or Cycles), because quite frankly they appear fantastic.

Comment: Note that these images are only 1024×512. I think all of them are available in higher resolution on HDRI Haven (e.g., forest.exr is [Ninomaru Teien](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=ninomaru_teien)).

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting

Answer (score 57):

The default HDR images can be found in your *installation folder*:

- [Windows] - `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender <version>\<version>\Datafiles\Studiolights\World\`
- [MacOS] - `/Applications/Blender/Contents/Resources/<version>/Datafiles/Studiolights/World/`
- [Linux] - `/opt/Blender <version>/<version>/Datafiles/Studiolights/World/` or `/usr/share/blender/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/world/`

In the *World* section, set the surface type to *Background* and the *Color* to use *Environment Texture*. Then select the HDR image you would like to use:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would have been useful if we can read anything about the node setup on your image :/

Comment: Take a look at this link (minute 9:29) https://vimeo.com/308999212 it's basically CTRL + T

Comment: wondering, is there a way to achieve blur effect of background like lookdev

Comment: Blender 2.8: The previews just got better than your renders ;)

Comment: In 2.90.0 I required Environment texture node, not Image Texture node... with the image node it did not render at all.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete :(

Comment: @10Rep what did not work for you? works for me Blender 2.91

Comment: @Emir I needed to add an exr file, not a hdr file. You should include that in your answer. And it still doesn't render properly.

Comment: @10Rep It's the same, if you look closely to the image you should notice that they are EXR files (The one in the image says "Sunset.exr")

Comment: @Emir That's all fine, but when I click "Render", it shows up without the enviroment. Same for you?

Comment: @10Rep That could be a different issue with the render settings; i highly recommend you to make acompletly new question with screenshots of your settings to get a different methods to solve that

Comment: Hello @10Rep :). If I may - HDRIs need to use the specific *Environment texture* node to be displayed correctly. The standard *Image texture* node only distorts them.

Comment: @Jaychm Michal yes I have understood that. But how do I use an environment texture node? I really dont understand that.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a list of corresponding HDRIs from HDRI Haven in **full resolution**.

[image]

1. City > [Portland Landing Pad](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=portland_landing_pad)
2. Courtyard > [Courtyard](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=courtyard)
3. Forest > [Ninomaru Teien](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=outdoor&h=ninomaru_teien)
4. Interior > [Hotel Room](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=indoor&h=hotel_room)
5. Night > [Moonless Golf](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=night&h=moonless_golf)
6. Studio > [Studio Small](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=studio&h=studio_small_01)
7. Sunrise > [Spruit Sunrise](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=outdoor&h=spruit_sunrise)
8. Sunset > [Venice Sunset](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=venice_sunset)