# Weird gray reflection on the liquid

Tags: modeling, shaders, lighting, glass

I'm relatively new to 3D modelling, I'm doing the BlenderGuru's Donut tutorial, I had to mess around with render properties, typically with the light paths' max bounces amount and the transmission, because the cup was really black and the light reflections looked unnatural (it looks better now, but still something is not ok). Also, the volume density looks nicer in viewport shading, there the coffee looks more like coffee without those weird gray gradients on top of the liquid like in this photo...

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533

Comment: @JachymMichal I think I made it look better? But the spots I mentioned are still there - https://imgur.com/a/nb6UxPj.

Comment: I think @JachymMicha is suggesting to use an HDRI environment texture to light up your scene. This will dramatically improve the realism of glass/liquid reflections. What you have here is a studio like lighting setup that's not an every day environment