# Is it possible to render as it is displayed in Material Preview?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting

I am trying to render an image. When I am in Material preview, it displays the objects in the scene without any lighting or shadows. All that can be seen is the texture.
When I render it however, what is displayed are the objects shaded with lighting. Is it possible to render an image the exact way it is previewed when it is in Material Preview?

Comment: Hello :). This thread should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off your overlays, then in the 3D viewport go to View -> Viewport Render Image. You can render even viewport animation from this menu.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get results as displayed in material preview-

Use eevee as render engine and go into world tab and choose environment texture as background.

Now,click open and go to where your blender is installed.

It is generally C:\program files\blender version

Now,go to files-studio lighting-world
Here you can get all the HDRIs that comes as default in blender.

Choose the HDRI that you are using in the material preview mode.