# Color differently after rendering

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color

I would like to ask for a help. I have different color after rendered by Eevee. Please see my attached file , the viewpoint color differently without any change .

Thank you,
Mandy

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Mandy, and welcome :). Are you sure you use the same HDRI for render and viewport? This answer could help [Which mode should i trust for lighting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/78972)

Comment: Hello Jachym , thanks for quick response :) I  have tried the HDRI from the link , but I still the same result with different color after rendered and save as png .

Comment: Hi :). Since I'm not good at guessing, you can [share the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much ;)  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=O1BkOGny" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/O1BkOGny/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem. Technical explanations are [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/colour-shift-when-viewing-render-outside-of-blender) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results).

To keep consistent colors:

1. Set *View Transform* to *Standard*.
2. **uncheck** *Save As Render* in the saving window
3. Enjoy consistent colors :).

[image]

[image]

Comment:      :)

Answer (score -1):

Too many wrong solutions regarding this issue. Refer to blender manual "Color Management" section first. In short, it doesn't matter of render engine. Just open the rendered file in Photoshop set color space "Monitor RGB : Display". Then you'll see that exact same color as in blender. But, you should apply this "Display" profile to the file so as you can keep the exact same color in other S/W at least on your computer and monitor. Surely your file may look differently on other devices