# Muted colors after rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color, color-management

Does anyone know how to sync colour profiles across Blender and exported PNG? The colour looks perfect in Blender, and in the rendered view, but the PNG itself is slightly duller. I'm assuming this is because my screen's profile is "Colour LCD" so it's showing me what I want to see on screen, but the file itself isn't retaining the same info.

I've already checked color management settings as recommended by other questions on here, and also render [using this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175212/color-differently-after-rendering).

To get around this, I'm taking a screenshot of the rendered image in Blender and using that for now, as it preserves the colour that I'm achieving in Blender, especially through to Instagram.

This is a ridiculous way of doing things, and it doesn't solve the issue long-term, especially for exporting video, where I'm getting the same result.

The swatches below show the correct colour on the left (captured via screenshot) and the rendered colour from Blender (exported as PNG) on the right.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

[image: colour test]

Comment: Hello and welcome... In general, when you render an animation, the best way to do it is with image sequences and using OpenExr to keep a linear color profile, that way, you could use any program (Like photoshop or After Effects) to interpret the color profile as you need it (like sRGB)

Comment: Thank you! I'll render the animation as an image sequence to manipulate the profile externally.

Just for context in case someone stumbles across this post with the same issue - The colour discrepancy that I'm seeing is the Image P3 profile being used by my Apple display (which also affects the Render Result preview in Blender) versus the sRGB profile of the exported image. If you don't align your monitor profile, your rendered images won't reflect the colour decisions you've made in Blender.