# Why my final render is brighter than the preview in the viewport?

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine

When I use the viewport to render, the result is different to the final render:

[image]
*Viewport Render*

[image]
*Final Render*

It's like the rendered image is brighter so I tried disabling the lights one by one to see if one of them is causing any problem. I also changed the light bounces from 12 to 1 but it made no difference. Neither *Bloom* nor *AO* or even changing the samples (from 128 to 64) makes a difference. I also tried rendering with 128 samples in the viewport and unfortunately it does not help.

[image]

**Q:** How to match the final render to the preview in the viewport?

Comment: @pijjoncha - if there is not any other light on side, it can be something with normal map or ... are you sure you use the same environment light (texture) with same rotation - for viewport and render? If its normal map (material setup) you can see if you hide a skull and try to add some another object like chrome sphere, from this object you can also see if envi match. Or post simplified blend where issue still persist via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us see your setup closer.

Comment: Related: [Which mode should i trust for lighting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/78972)