# Why can't I get my reflections to show in render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I can only see reflections in shader viewport , why can't I get them to render? I have specular refractions on in the render engine (evee) & material. But still get this grey image when I view render or animaton

[image]

Comment: Have you got an HDRi background?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting