# Glossy object looks different in rendered view (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

A glossy  object looks perfect in material preview ,but when I come to render mode (I try to use cycle), everything looks completely different.

[image]

Comment: Your environment is grey hence no reflections... It looks different in the preview because there is an hdri already set for convenience.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting