# Render looks way different from viewport render mode. How can I fix this?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, light, hdri

I'm trying to make a test render of my model. But everytime I render it the render looks completely different from the viewport. The viewport is in render mode so it should look something like that, but this doesn't come even close.

I'm using cycles renderer. And my world note is just the standard one so nothing installed there.  There are 2 sun's in the scene both set to 0.5.  I've tried different hdris but they all have the exact same outcome. I've pressed alt+h to see if there was anything hiddden in my scene that blocked the background and nothing shows up so I don't think that's the problem. I've also copied it to a new Blend file to see if there was anything wrong with the file itself but it also happens there so it must be something in my settings I guess. But I just can't find out which one

[image]

this is how it looks in the viewport render.

[image]

And this is how it looks when I render it.

I really don't know how to fix this so I hope someone can help me here

Answer (score 7):

**It looks different in the preview because in *Material Preview Shading* there is an HDRI already set up for convenience, but that HDRI is not used for *Render Shading***.

### [image]

How to use an HDR image as environment.

In the world section, set the surface to *Background*, assign an *Environment Texture* to the *color* slot and then select any HDRI image you want to use:

[image]

Enable *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* to override the viewport settings:

[image]
*Gif from: [How can I render an object with an hdr background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81011/31447)*

---

### Related

- [How to use 2.8's default HDRI's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/31447)
- [Which mode should i trust for lighting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/31447)