# how can I turn on HDRI for my rendering?

Tags: modeling, rendering, osx

I'm new to blender, so sorry if my question sounds dumb. I was following tutorial, and built this model:

[image]

After building it, I was trying to render. Because I'm on mac laptop, so of course the render turn out very shitty.

[image]

But the most confusing thing is after this, my viewport became the same low quality as the render image.

[image]

My render mode is on Eevee.

After receiving answers, I was able to find viewport shading in look dev mode. But in rendered mode, I could not access.
[image]

Comment: "*Because i'm on mac laptop, so of course the render turn out very shitty.*" Computer platform has absolutely no influence in render quality. Please make the title of the post match the contents of the question

Comment: It looks like you haven't setup the HDRI for the render.

Comment: A common confusion. The first image is likely using the "viewport shading", which by default adds an HDR image to light the scene, but that is not used at render time.

Comment: @RobertGützkow thank you so much for the post! it really helped me. Unfortunately I cannot access viewport shading at my rendered mode. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos hi Im very new to the software so sorry about that! Do you know how i can achieve better rendering on mac? I read couple of posts and everyone has been saying that Mac osx does not come with cuda or OpenCL. I'm very lost.

Comment: @susu Hi thank you so much! do you know I can make it appear in my rendered image?

Comment: If you can not access the menu, you should file a bug report (Main menu > Help > Report a bug). Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this/179977#179977

Comment: "*I read couple of posts and everyone has been saying that Mac osx does not come with cuda or OpenCL. I'm very lost.*" Mac platform is generally considered inferior for 3D work for lack of features and poor hardware support, but that generally affects performance not quality. It means rendering on a Mac for the same quality level will be slower and less efficient, but images should be roughly the same visually.

Comment: @ChelseaChan search in this site questions on how to set an HDRI for the world.