# Look Dev Mode Transparent background

Tags: rendering, texturing, light

I'm trying to find a way to render my image in Look Dev mode with a transparent background if this is possible.

I have tried to emulate the dev mode in view port shading, I added a HDRI image, lights, but cannot get a better result than the look Dev mode.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning down the *World Opacity* under *Viewport Shading* menu already?

Comment: I turned down the Opacity. Once I render, the image is flat. 

https://ibb.co/52zBtPX

Comment: You have to enable *Transparent* under *Render Properties > Film* for rendering... two different things you're asking for.

Comment: Also: The image is "flat" because you also have to setup an environment for rendering: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179977/31447 (lookdev is for preview only and has no effect on rendering)

Comment: Yep, all the things worked, well, I got a better result.

Thank you.