# Problems with rendering textures in Blender 2.8 with Macbook Pro 2015

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I'm new to Blender.

I don't have any NVIDIA or AMD, just default Mac OS graphic card.

Can I render 3D & texture with my default settings? I turned off on render viewport "Scene lights & Scene world" and I can see the texture but not in the final render.

On my viewport render I can see the full texture but when I go to render with EEVEE the image I just see a "glossy" result. Why?

Here's two photo's for reference

[image: Rendered Viewport version]

[image: Rendered version]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render looks way different from viewport render mode. How can I fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: The angle of the camera is different as well...

Comment: @brockmann Yes i know, it's just random views, it's not that the point! But thank you so much, i'm tryna figure it out with this link.

Comment: It is one of your issues, because at that angle the reflection is different. The main issue is described in the linked answer (TLDR; your environment is grey thus no reflection)

Comment: If you want reflections on the surface, you have to put something that gets reflected. The reflection will also be determined by the placement of the camera in reference to the object and whatever is being reflected on the surface. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black

Comment: @brockmann Thank you so much!

Comment: @susu Thanks for your words, i will check it the link!