# HDRI doesn't show up in the final render

Tags: hdri

I've got a problem again. :)
My HDRI does show up in the viewport, no matter if it's in renderview oder solid, etc.

[image]

Unfortunaly, it won't show up in my final render. Since it's the main light, it's just dark.

Comment: please provide your blend file, so we can what's going on

Comment: Sure, how do I share the blend file here?

Comment: open this page https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AAG8VMRw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AAG8VMRw/)

Comment: Make sure *Scene World* in viewport shading is ticked: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179977/31447 If you'd like to preview the hdr in the viewport as well.

Comment: thank you, that was fast! ;) can you please, before uploading your blend file, go to file -> external data -> pack all into .blend, then save the blend file and then upload again? Because then all textures/images etc are in the blend file and i don't have to fill it manually.

Comment: @Chris Checked the file already, as I suspected: *Scene World* is not enabled...

Comment: Ohh, thank you both! The file is still uploading, but where exactly can I find the checkbox? (Sorry, I am a noob! ;D)

Comment: See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkwqA.gif (or just click the link I've posted in my comment above)

Comment: @brockmann: no problem - i don't want to "steal" your answer -> why don't you write it as answer? but...by the way...although i checked your checkbox in her blend file - when i render it - it is still black. Did you try to render? ;)

Comment: I also tried, it is still black. :I I'm not sure what you mean by writing it as an answer, but  I just click on "add comment".

Comment: @Chris Not about "stealing" the answer, just wanted to save some time and let you know

Comment: So uhh ... is there a way to fix it?

Comment: of course ;) i try to figure it out Could you upload the new blend file?

Comment: No pressure. Just disable your "Cube" object for rendering (or delete it) and it's going to render as expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yPbH.png

Comment: Guys! It works! Thank you very much. I learned a lot from Blender today. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) (No 2)