# What's wrong with my render?

Tags: rendering, materials

I have a scene that is pretty much ready for render, and in the render mode of the viewport it looks good. But whenever I try to render it, materials change and the lighting goes wonky. I can't see any reason why this would happen. I'm using the current version of blender.

[image: Rendered]

[image: Viewport]

Comment: Are you rendering in _Eevee_ or _Cycles_? Could you provide some screenshots with your question to show how the materials change and go "wonky"?

Comment: or provide your blend file...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render looks way different from viewport render mode. How can I fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: I've edited it to have screenshots. Unfortunately, I can't share the as it is too big.

Comment: It looks as if some parts of the scene were not lit and I can't see lights in your collection.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth There is a sun light out of frame. It all looks good in the viewport render, so I don't think it's the lights.