# Problems with HDRI map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, hdri

Hi i have a pretty nice render in the viewport but when i turning on the scene world check it's differ from the viewport (obviously, im copied the default hdri map from the blender folder (night.exr) i tried to edit the settings but they are not change anything help pls.
[image]

[image: What render i need]

[image: what render i have]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render looks way different from viewport render mode. How can I fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: I guess you are trying to use an *Image Texture* node instead of an *Enviroment Texture* node, recommend follow the steps in the link above and see whether that fixes the lighting.

Comment: Im already using the environment texture node

Comment: Cool. However, as it stands we can only guess what you're doing wrong. Did you follow the guide? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179977/31447 Still nothing? Otherwise I'd suggest share your blend without the model, preferably using: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, but i can't share with you my .blend file, can we solve this problem by using screenshots? Can you name what screenshots you need?

Comment: Why not? Just delete the geometry in the blend and share it, the only thing we are interessted in is the *Environment* (World Settings) ... Again, did you follow the guide?

Comment: Yes, i followed the guide

Comment: I have textures which was imported from Substance painter, send it?

Comment: Textures have nothing to do with the overall lighting of the scene (the HDRI).

Comment: check the edited question

Comment: I cannot really see it in the screenshot because it's so dark... is the sphere completely surrounded by a tunnel or something or is it "beneath the open sky"?

Comment: surrounded by tunnel

Comment: If you want to match the preview just disconnect the principled volume node in you world shader, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1vPa.png However, you **don't need any hdri at all** because your "scene" is enclosed by geometry and the light send out from the hdri is blocked by that.

Comment: thx so much, u really helped me

Comment: As you might see by now, impossible to figure out without a screenshot of your world shader or the blend file. I recommend put more effort into your questions, remember that only you have access to your scene, only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for sharing the blend file @someone12512
This is what I found

**1. Rendering just as is, this is how it looks like as you might already know**
[image]

**This is your world node settings, as you set it up**
[image]

**2. This is what it looks like when I changed the settings**
[image]

**This is what I changed**
[image]

So, I guess the problem was with the volume node connected to the world
You can try different values or even create a cube and let it be the volume, idk how that could change things... But this is what I found
Hope it helps