# Why does Blender not use my viewport lighting for render output?

Tags: rendering

I am new to rendering in Blender

[image]
[image]

My rendering tab shows this:
[image]

The problem here is that the lighting in the viewport is different from the output, and I can't understand why.

And this is the render:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking and what is the problem, output menu is same for both cycles and eevee. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: hello, where do you see any mention of Cycles in the Output?

Comment: I see the rendering is completely different from the one you can see here, and this is in Eevee, while if I use Cycles, I get the same view I get in the output file, without lights.

Comment: Okay, but we can't see the rendering you are seeing. And what is shown above is the _Material Preview_ shading, this shouldn't be too different from the render result in _Eevee_, but in the default it uses some preview HDRI to light the objects, whereas the render uses the light and environment that's in the scene. I can't see your world settings, but I see in the outliner you have no light in your scene - so of course the render is without any lights, no matter if _Cycles_ or _Eevee_.

Comment: Added rendering. The issue is that the lighting in the viewport is not taken for the output render. How can I make it take the environment HDR image for lighting?

Comment: The lighting you see in the viewport is just for preview, it won't affect your render, you can check `Scene Lights` and `Scene World` from `Viewport Shading` if you want your viewport render to look like your final render.

Comment: @PolyMad By the way, what the Rendering Tab shows... those tabs at the top are shortcuts to switch between different layouts of the UI. It's not automatically showing a render result. To have the render showing there, you must at least once render your scene by pressing F12 or from the menu _Render_ > _Render Image_. I would suggest you watch some basic tutorials on getting started with Blender, using the interface and what all these things mean.

Comment: Hi :). This question should help: [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/78972)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render looks way different from viewport render mode. How can I fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so the thing is, what you're viewing in the viewport, that's Material Preview Mode. In Material Preview Mode, blender applies a default HDRI (World Lighting) so that we can see the materials without any lighting.

Then comes Rendered Dispay mode, there we're supposed to add in lights and everything, so that we, the user have full control. But, if you want the lights from Material preview mode to carry over to Rendered Display mode, all you have to do is uncheck scene lights and scene world from the dropdown next rendered display icon on the top right, as shown below.

[image]

If you want to render it in as well, all you have to do is go to the Shader editor, and switch it from object to World

[image]

Add in an enviroment texture node by shift + A and searching Environment Texture, then click on open.

[image]

Navigate to where you've installed blender, and go to the relative data path mentioned below.

> Blender Foundation\Blender{Version}\{VersionNumber}\datafiles\studiolights\world

There you can find all the HDRI's blender use. The default one should be Forest.exr

Load it up and connect it to the Background node.
Now you should be able to render it in.

Comment: But still, simply unchecking _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_ in the _Render Viewport Shading_ will not use the preview lighting when it comes to a real render after you press F12.

Comment: Updated the current answer to include that as well, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you, I solved and understood everything (I think lol).

Comment: If you have any doubts regarding this, please feel free to ask.
Always happy to help.