# My Blender can't display correct metal material

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, lighting

I found my Blender can't display metal material correctly, so I tried to open a new clear project and just create a pure monkey and a metal material to it, the material only be modified the color to C0C0C0,Metallic to 1 and Roughness to 0. the result shows like below and this is not expected!! Does anyone know what's the problem??? [image]

I have light in the scene( just create a new project with basic settings, one light and one camera) and from the metal preview it shows the same result.

The weird thing is I found if unchecked "Scene World" then it looks better in viewport preview but no help for render.. why??

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you give it a metal material, it needs something to reflect, at least one light, or an HDRI image. If it still doesn't work maybe you have a graphic card problem?

Comment: Press Z and select "material preview" - how does it look there?

Comment: Yes, I light in Scene and it shows the same when I select material preview.  And I found if unchecked "Viewport shading"-> "Lighting"->"Scene World" then it looks better in viewport preview but no help for render.. why??

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this