# What is causing this reflection on a surface? (Blender Guru coffee cup tutorial)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, reflection

I am following a beginner tutorial on Blender Guru’s YouTube channel.

I am creating a glass cup with liquid inside, and I am using the Volume Absorption settings on the Material panel in order to create the desired effect on the liquid.

As far as I know, I’ve followed the tutorial exactly, but as you can see from the attached image. There is some odd yellow/gold band as the top front of the liquid.

Normally, I would experiment with different settings, but as a complete beginner, I don’t really know where to go and what to adjust. With my extremely limited experience, I think it is something to do with reflections, as it looks like there is something else going on with that area, but I haven’t really got a clue.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

[image: Picture of cup with coffee inside. There is a weird yellow/gold band at the top of the liquid]

Comment: Hello :). Could this be a reflection from an HDRI? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/78972

Comment: That’s what I was thinking, although I didn’t know what it was called. I will certainly give that a try. Am I able to set it to something generic that wouldn’t give me those reflections? Also, how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Follown the link, it's all explained there :).

Comment: Thanks Jachym. Ok, I am *reeeally* beginner so I’m not sure where all the options are :) I’ll try it out later and see if I can get through it.

Comment: No problem, say where exactly you're stuck and I'll do my best to help :). But the linked post should cover the basics

Comment: It is because the liquid overlapping with the glass. If you are talking about the yellow looking area. This happened to me too.

Comment: Thanks Jachym! @BlenderNueva do you mean the liquid is going outside the bounds of the glass? My intention was to have the liquid slightly intersect the inside face of the glass.

Comment: the liquid is too close to the glass.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to fix it. After experimenting with the scale of the liquid and HDRI and shading settings, I found out it was neither of these.

I hid the liquid by using the eye icon while in render view and I noticed the line was still there, and when I switched to object view, it still looked like there was a still a liquid shape. What I think I did was duplicate the vertices and right clicked rather than make a separate object. I then created a new liquid layer on top.

So what I did was click on the cup in Edit Mode and then Merge Vertices > By Distance. This effectively removed that additional liquid layer I had in the cup object.

[image: Fixed!]