# How do I change the first color in the shading tab?

Tags: shaders

This one I surrounded in red in the screenshot.

I think it's the reason why my 3D creation look so black and I want to get rid of it.

How do I change it to gray, just like the one next to it?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). That's just your HDRI preview. It being black often means your GPU drivers aren't fully supported.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to momentarily disable it so that I can still see something closer to the final render ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but perhaps this could help: [Which mode should i trust for lighting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170533/78972)

Comment: Ok solved it! You might be right for the reason the sort of black disk is black, but it had absolutely nothing to do with why my texture was all black, it's actually because the color in the node "ColorRamp" was set to black by default. So I just set the color to a very light grey and now it looks all nice and clean.

Comment: Glad you solved it, feel free to post a full answer so others can benefit from it :)