# Why is my Render coming out grey and flat?

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials

I followed a Youtube video to make a disco ball from a mesh UV sphere. It looks great until I go into rendered and then it just looks grey and flat. Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

[Rendered Image[image: ][1]]

[image: Solid]

Comment: Need more details, like which renderer are you using, a screenshot of the material node setup and the world nodes.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your disco ball is made up of mirrors, it is mirroring your perfectly grey world...perfectly.  Thus: a grey ball.

I recommend moseying over to PolyHaven (formerly HDRI haven, https://polyhaven.com/hdris ) and choosing an appropriate HDRI map that you can add to your background.  This way, your mirror ball will have something nice to reflect. Once you have one, go into the shading tab, change Object to World in the node tab, and set it up like this:

[image: image texture with an exr image set going into the background node going into the world output surface node]

Comment: Thank you @kirbinator !! You might have noticed im very new to Blender, super appreciate your help!