# My world(?) lighting isn't showing in the render

Tags: lighting

[image: render showing no lighting while display does]

I'm not sure what specifics I need to put, so if anybody needs any specifics then they can comment and I'll reply.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this