# How can I render in Blender while preserving the metallic shine, background appearance, and reflections?

Tags: rendering, lighting, reflection, world

I have a project in Blender. The appearance of my project during rendering is shown in the first image, but I want the metallic reflections and the "reflection of the Earth" on the background, as shown in the second image, to remain the same. When I render, the metallic shine and the background disappear. How should I render it?

[image]

[image]

I tried the method in this tutorial, but I couldn't succeed, there was no change.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVBXQWIcuUk

[image]

Comment: In the Viewport Shading panel that you show in your first image you need to enable the Scene Lights and Scene World options in order to see your current scene settings. Your object is metallic so it will reflect the HDRI image you've chosen in your world material, this HDRI may be not the best, maybe choose another one

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170533/which-mode-should-i-trust-for-lighting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this/