# My render preview in the viewport and my final rendered image look nothing alike (my render preview looks far better)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: Renders]

Above is the final rendered image (left) and the render preview (right)

Comment: please **[edit]** your question and use the tools from this site to upload images, so that they show as part  of the question and not as links. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Comment: Some settings have different values between render and preview. Modifiers, for instance. Just a guess but give it a check.

Comment: Hello :). Render preview uses an HDRI background for lighting. It seems like your render has just a solid color background.

Comment: Related: [How to use default HDRIs in Renders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/78972)