# I want my render to look more like my lookdev

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

The left picture is the Cycles render preview , and the right one is the material preview. I would rally prefer to get a render like the material preview but if i go in eevee which does get me some success but the reflective photorealism goes away which is also a primary requirement , how do i solve this , how can i make my render more like my lookdev and remain reflectively photorealistic at the same time

[image]

**EDIT**
I added the exact same HDRI that i added in the lookdev and also increased the samples from 32 to 256(max my potato can handle) and had some success in illuminating the the camera mount and the internals of the camera but still trying to achieve some brightness in the lenses

Comment: At the moment, you need *samples*. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: The main difference is that the material preview is using an envirionment with an HDR by default, not your lights or the environment set in the world, in order to get the same results use the same HDRi. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders  Also you might want to check out this post on rendering glass in cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles. And yes you need more samples.

Comment: @susu okay thank you , will definately try

Comment: Did you modify the glass shader?

Comment: @susu its actually not a glass shader , its a principle shader with high transmission and low alpha