# how to render an image without effect of scene world

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, scene, world

I am new to 3d and blender. My question is how can I get an image rendered as on the left side of the image. I can see the **Scene World** is making the difference. Is there a way to render the image without the effect of the scene world?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question, if the image on the left is the one you want and not the one you want to avoid, the way to render a scene with those "world" reflections is by adding an HDRI as the surface input in the "World Properties" tab on the lower right.

Comment: This is confusing. You have the result you want on the left, but you are still asking how to.

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf, but when I render the image, Render->Render Image, it is producing an image that is on the right side.

Comment: Can you share your .blend file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens when you check/uncheck the *Scene World* option, is that blender toggles between the lighting you have set up yourself, and a pre-built (and hidden) HDRI that provides lighting and reflections (as seen by default in the *Shading Tab*)

So, to get the same look for your render , what you are looking for is the effect of HDRI lighting. Go to the world section of your shading tab and add and **Environment Texture** (not an *Image Texture*). You can use any HDRI you want, but the one that is being used in your example is in your blender folder at `....2.92/datafiles/studiolights/world` and the image is `forest.exr` (there are others there too). You can also find many free ones online - one of the most popular places is HDRI Haven (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/).

If you want the lighting and reflection influence but don't want the image as your "background", you can mix the *Environment Texture* with another Background (I used the default) using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *light Path* node as a Mix Factor (as shown below):

[image: HDRI]

Comment: [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179863/31447)

Comment: @Chirstopher Bennett, aha, I see. color in world property needed an hdri image rather than a solid color. It also seems Vector is also playing a part in the final rendering. Thanks very much for your detailed explanation.