# When I render in cycles my object is pink

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

My object has a pinkish shade to it and I don't know why, when I open a new project it works fine but in this project it is like this. I tried to check for missing files but with no results, I applied some basic colors but the same thing. Ask for more information.
In eevee mode it is fine.

the shader nodes of one object, and in the composition is nothing

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

also if it helps

[image]

---

My file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_-7M2j-Ztm7gS07fRXrgoYetk1dDNjB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Difficult to say why entirely without the blend file, but maybe you have the output note for the shader set to “EEVEE only“ and thus cycles has no shader instructions to work with. Shaders can have multiple outputs, one for each render engine that may use the seder.

Comment: I will attach the blender file if u want to see what is wrong

Comment: @Timaroberts yes it does. He says “in EEVEE it works fine.“

Comment: @Roader yes, please do.

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMxGy2jYx2D-1FjRCFOVXX-RJnyZd0Es/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I read to fast, and twice too to be sure. My fault :)

Comment: @Roader please show show an image of your shader nodes, you may use https://pasteall.org/blend/ to upload your file

Comment: Here it is again https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_-7M2j-Ztm7gS07fRXrgoYetk1dDNjB/view?usp=sharing now the better verion

Comment: OK, that is kind of weird. I will look at the blend file…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the missing HDRI. (This was my first thought but I am surprised that it works in Eevee. Probably because you used an empty *Image Texture* node.)

**Solution:** In the world background (use the node editor) plug an ***Environment Texture*** node into the *Emission* node and specify an HDRI.

[How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders)

Of course, you can use just a simple color for the world background. This will fix it, too.

Comment: A thanks isn't enough but can't do anything else, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting SPACEBAR to play the animation, even if there is no animations in the file, although difficult to say exactly what's going on without the blend file.