# My PBR Texture looks better in Viewport than in the Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, pbr

i'm rendering an Image of Bane's Mask in Blender. Its on a wet road, which looks high-res in viewport.
This road looks very flat and dry after rendering in Cycles.

Viewport result:
[image]

Render result:
[image]

Comment: maybe it has to do with your node setup?

Comment: Thank you, but what could it be ? I experience this for the first time..

Comment: Hey :). It's because of lighting - Viewport preview uses a HDRI to light the scene, which gives all those cool reflections.

Comment: please show a screenshot of your Shader Editor

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nthHKlwcpiPU5cqVDDAEwtTrsXsxTk4j/view?usp=sharing this is the shader :)

Comment: @JachymMichal that looks like the right direction, but still, i think after turning "scene world" on, i think it looks different :/

Comment: Well, yes, you need to add a HDRI to your scene world :). https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/78972

Comment: So i added a HDRI to my scene world and somehow it still doesnt work. Probably i did something wrong. :( I have to go afk for a moment.

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the material preview render in the viewport automatically uses an environment texture from “C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.91/datafiles/studiolights/world” as the world background, but by default the rendered world background is solid grey. You can load one of these backgrounds and pipe it into the world’s background color with an Environment Texture node.