# Render Picture id to dark

Tags: rendering

every time whem I'm rendering my picture it is very dark.
[image]

But my Layout looks like this:

[image]

Maybe the Problem is that I rotatet the light in the viewport shading?

Without rotation it looks more like the picture that I rendered[image]

If I rotate everything about 180 degree it looks the way I want but that wwould mess up my animation :(

What can I do to fix this.

Comment: Hello and welcome. it looks like your scene does not have any lights. The included HDRIs are for the render preview viewport. if you wanna use those [see this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders/179863)

Comment: in the Viewport Shading panel you need to enable the Scene Lights and Scene World options