# Render different than render preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I've got a problem with rendering this scene. What I get, looks totally different compared to render view, with these options turned on, also changes in light paths, setting bounces etc. doesn't seem to affect anything.
What did I do wrong? Is there something in the Render settings, Preferences, or my computer (worst option, hopefully not)?

File:
[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders)

Comment: If you look at "Sampling" in your scene properties, you can see one difference, which is that you are using many fewer samples in the viewport.  So the viewport will have more rendering artifacts (sometimes called fireflies.)  Another major difference is that you are using a denoiser in your render but not in the viewport.

Comment: @Emir unfortunately, no

Comment: @MartyFouts thank you, I did some changed and updated the post. Deleted denoiser and also increased viewport sampling, it looks the same. All render settings attached

Comment: For me it looks like you have an HDRI for the render preview, but no HDRI for the Final Render, that's why I suggested the answer to add a world HDRI. There is basically no reflection on the final other than the floor and wall

Comment: @Emir where to check on that? I've got it in my World Properties (surface-background, color-hdri) also scene lights and scene world options checked

Comment: can you attach the blend file so we can look at it?

Comment: @kuksu Sorry, this is a good tutorial about it [video](https://youtu.be/qtvD59m8tv4?t=77)

Comment: @Emir thank you, I watched this and everything is right, so this is still unsolved..

Comment: @MartyFouts just attached a file in post, hopefully there will be some kind of answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a fourth diamond, called "Diamond1" in your scene.  You have it enabled for render but not for viewport shading:

[image: Diamond1 in render but not viewport]

When I disable it from the render, the two match as closely as can be expected:

[image: disabled in render]

Viewport

[image: viewport]

Render

[image: render]

The remaining difference is because there are more samples in the render than the viewport.