# What's the setup to reproduce the BSDF examples?

Tags: rendering, materials

I am starting to explore materials and rendering in Blender, and as an exercise, I wanted to reproduce the examples found on the [BSDF manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html) using the Python API. I mean this one

[image]

and the other two.

How do I do that? The ball is ok - but I don't even know how to google a question for the reflected images.

Comment: Hi :). Are you asking how to get the reflection? [Simply use an HDRI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/78972).

Comment: @JachymMichal - yep, that's 80% of it, thanks. It's hard to google for something you don't know the name of. It'd be great to also know what the materials settings were, but I can get that by trial and error.

Comment: the material settings are to leave everything as default, except for the setting that's named in the first column.  Each ball represents the chosen setting set to the value (0.0, 0.1, et cetera) at the head of the column.