# Hdri background does not show up when I export my blender model

Tags: 3d-view, hdri, gltf

I am very new to Blender. Only been using it for a couple of days.

I have a 3d model(s) in an hdri environment and would like to export the model with the hdri background so that I can view the model while moving the hdri environment in 360 degrees.

When I export it in glb/gltf format, I'm only able to view one of the models with no hdri background.
When I export it in fbx format, I am able to view all my models but not with the hdri background.

Basically, what I've noticed is that when I view my exported blender file on Windows 3D Viewer,  it appears like the material preview mode on the blender viewport shading. I want it to export it the way it appears on the Rendered Preview mode on the Viewport Shading.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: For what it's worth, there have been at least 2 different draft/vendor extensions to glTF proposed for embedding HDRIs. None have been accepted by Khronos or implemented in Blender, because they add a lot to the size of the file, and most assets are generally interchangeable among multiple HDRIs.  So for now I think you have to handle the HDRIs separately from glTF files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work this way. The HDRI is part of the environment setting and I don't think you can export it with the model. You need to set the HDRI in the importing program. Does the Windows 3D Viewer support HDRIs?

Blender uses [build-in HDRIs for the material preview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/107598). For rendering, you need to set up the HDRI in the world settings.

Furthermore, [most file export formats don't support exporting textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57531/107598). However, you can re-create the material in the importing program and import the textures and the HDR image (if supported) manually. The [glTF file format](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) is an exception because it supports textures and basic material settings - but no HDRI either.

In [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/editor/) for example, the HDRI can be uploaded into the Environment slot. (It must be a *.hdr file, *.exr files are not supported.) Texture images can be specified in the material settings below. If you use the glTF format the images will be imported from the *.glb file and assigned automatically.

[image: screenshot threejs]