# How do I light everything evenly in render (similar to Material Preview viewport shading)?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

How do I light everything evenly in render (similar to Material Preview viewport shading)?
I want my render to be identical to this viewport screenshot: [image: viewport image]

But render looks like this:
[image: render image]

Also, how do I make glossy object like in the viewport?

Comment: the material preview mode uses built in HDRIs (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/107598). For glossiness use a low *Roughness* value (0 to 0.2) in the *Principled BSDF* node in your material node setup.

Answer (score 1):

Use HDRIs in the scene to get views like this. There are various websites that provides free HDRIs. Then go into the Render properties->Film->Transparent(Tick this one) and you'll get the view like this in render too.
[image]

Comment: how would it work out using video?