# How to render the same image as in the ViewPort

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting, hdri

Rendered Image has less details than image in ViewPort. I provide the blend file.
Do you can fix my blend file and make the rendered image from the Renderer to be the same as image as in ViewPort, please.

And I need explanation what is wrong?

1. Looks that ViewPort has its own HDR image with forest. How can I obtain the same HDR image.
2. Rendered image have less details, and shallow shadows.

I try a lot of experiments but I failed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of Render vs wievPort]

Blender 3.1.2 Cycles
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use built-in default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I download HDR image from https://polyhaven.com/a/ninomaru_teien

Comment: In your word setup, you need to mute (key M) or reset (Backspace) the *Color Dodge* and *Bright/Contrast* nodes and use the forest HDRI (see duplicate question). Furthermore, move the *Point* light into the *Lighting* collection and uncheck this collection to disable it for rendering (=no additional lights, just the HDRI). Then the render will look like in the viewport. If you want to have your viewport look like the render you need to tick the *[X ]Scene Lights* and *[X] Scene World* checkboxes in the viewport shading options (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlih5.jpg)

Comment: SOLVED !  @Blunder Thak You!