# How to add lights so that this will look like the screenshot in cycles render?

Tags: lighting

[image]

The screenshot is of material preview. It is probably due to and HDRI. How can I create such lights?

Comment: You can find the HDRI that are used in the Material preview, they are in a folder. Or use a similar HDRI. Or create some area lights.

Comment: probable answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders