# Why is viewport much better than camera after render?

Tags: rendering, camera

I can't understand why the viewport renders like this:

[image]

but when I render with my camera it renderers like this:

[image]

[image]
I can see that it must have something to do with these settings but can't seem to apply them to the camera. Apologies if this a very basic question.

Comment: The viewport is using a built-in hdri - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders

Comment: Thank you, but would this also affect the colour and material of the door?

Comment: if it has a glossy component at all, I'd say yeah

Comment: OK, so added exr and setup nodes but still no change. Is there a setting which enables transparency of materials when rendered. Th glass in the door should show the environment outside but doesn't in camera view.

Comment: I'm no expert at eevee so maybe I'm getting something wrong.  This is what I'm getting out of the box with the forest hdr applied.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqT1d.jpg  It's not an exact match because the material preview is also blurred.

Comment: If you've disabled Scene Lights and Scene World what you'll see in Rendered preview will be the scene as lit by the default HDRI, but when you render Blender uses the lights and HDRI that are really set for your scene and world, so first thing please reactivate the 2 options so that we can see what it gives in preview