# How do I render my blend without Scene Lights and Scene World using HDRI lighting?

Tags: rendering, scene, hdri, world

I tried to render my keyboard and it renders with Scene World. I tried to change the lighting from Scene World to HDRI (with HDRI it looks good (1)), but then it still ended up a mess.

Where is my mistake, can anyone help me, please?

Viewport, without Scene World or Scene Lights, looks good and I need to render it:

[image]

Render:

[image]

I tried to apply these settings to make all the lighting in the rendering look like the first image (viewport), following advice from the Internet.

[image]

What I got after trying to solve the problem with 3rd Image:

[image: What I got after trying to solve the problem with 3rd Image]

I just want my rendering to look like the first image (Using HDRI City.exe instead of Scene Lights or World Scene)

Comment: Please add your images into your question rather than making folks click on links to view them! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: If you want your image to look like the first image, remove the lights, and use the HDRI that is used by default in Material Preview node, you can find it in your harddrive: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-built-in-default-hdris-in-renders#:~:text=The%20default%20HDR%20images%20can,%5CDatafiles%5CStudiolights%5CWorld%5C

Comment: @moonboots It's like what I did on 3rd image, no?

Comment: @JohnEason I tried adding images using icons when was writing question, I does apply only using Imgur, I thought.

Comment: third image you're using the scene world, but the setting of your scene world is wrong, maybe open the Shader Editor, switch it to World mode, lower down the Backround node strength

Comment: @Supp0rt1337 You can just drag and drop images straight into the editor when writing your question if you wish, but clicking the image icon should work as well.