How to render metall elements with Ctrl F12 rendering
I want to create sprite sheet in Blender 3.6 from 3D animation. When I try to create frames(Ctrl+F12), metal parts of my character is not rendered correctly. I was wondering if it is possible to fix it in blender?

Edit
My question was associated with similar one by the link Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black? But it doesn't answer my initial question. It is also a bit different question. Let me explain why.
Author of the post Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black? is saying that a text becomes black when glossy shader is applied to the text. I understand it like the author cannot see glossiness of a text in blender at all.
I am able to see metal glossiness of my object in blender. It works as expected. My issue is related to Render Animation tool. So, while I see my metal object in Blender Layout, the same metal object is black-ish at images which I get when press Ctrl+F12. The output images don't reflect metal object properly.
Regardless of this, I read answers of this post. They suggested 2 fixes. Apply proper lighting and add surface to be reflected on my object. It doesn't do any effect in my case.
Edit2
I added HDRI image to world environment and it helped to fix the issue

Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/107598

if you are in Material preview, you'll see a default HDRI image reflected on the surface of your metallic object, but this HDRI image won't be used for render, if you want something else than your background color to be reflected in your render, you need to give an HDRI image to your World. You would have seen that if you have switched to the Rendered preview mode (as long as its Scene World option is activated).

Can you please elaborate, what you mean by "give an HDRI image to your world"? I need only sprites from my animation which will be used in flipbook in Unreal Engine. I'm not going to use it Blender eventually.

Ok, I read post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black and I think get what you mean here. I need to add an object to be reflected. I will try it...

It didn't help. The author of the post asked about an issue when he applied a glossy shader to an object and It doesn't work. In my case it works good. I see glossiness/metallicity in blender. The issue will come when I try to run Ctrl+F12 tool. I don't see glossiness on images which I get in the end. But it is still good in blender

Have you given an HDRI image to your World? Maybe share your file (pack your image: File > External Data > Pack Resources)

I eventually did it. I did wrong attachment of image to World and it didn't work. Now I added it right and see glossiness. Thanks for the help!
